# Using fourier transforms to solve odes

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image]

In the very last line of the solution that i have given i got the residue to be (e^(iaz))/2i which when multiplied by 2pii gives me pie^(iaz) now from this i don't understand how they got rid of z to write I(a) in terms of just a.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming suitable conditions on $f$,
$$
              \widehat{f''}+2i\widehat{f'}-2\widehat{f} = \widehat{g} \\
                 -s^{2}\widehat{f}-2s\widehat{f}-2\widehat{f}=\widehat{g}\\
                 \{s^{2}+2s+1\}\widehat{f}=-\widehat{g} \\
                \widehat{f}=-\frac{\widehat{g}}{s^{2}+2s+1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
          f= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\hat{g}(s)e^{isx}}{s^{2}+2s+1}ds \\
   = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-ist}\frac{e^{isx}}{s^{2}+2s+1}dtds \\
   = -i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{is(x-t)}}{s^{2}+2s+1}ds dt \\
$$
The roots of $s^{2}+2s+1$ are $-1\pm i$. If $x-t > 0$, then $e^{is(x-t)}$ decays for $s$ in the upper half-plane, which allows you to close the contour in the upper half-plane and gives a value of
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{is(x-t)}}{(s-(-1-i))(s-(-1+i))}ds \\
   = \left.\frac{e^{is(x-t)}}{s-(-1-i)}\right|_{s=-1+i}=\frac{e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}}{2i}
$$
If $x-t < 0$, then $e^{is(x-t)}$ decays for $s$ in the lower half-plane, which allows you to close the contour in the lower half-plane (but the contour is negatively oriented) and gives a value of
$$
     = -\left.\frac{e^{is(x-t)}}{s-(-1+i)}\right|_{s=-1-i}=-\frac{e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}}{-2i}
$$
Combining these,
$$
    f(x) = \frac{-i}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-|x-t|}dt,
$$
which can be written as
$$
     f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}dt
            -\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}dt.
$$
**Now check the final answer:**
\begin{align}
     f'(x) = & -\frac{1}{2}g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)(-i-1)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}dt \\
           & +\frac{1}{2}g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)(-i+1)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}dt \\
     f''(x) = & -\frac{1}{2}(-i-1)g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)(-i-1)^{2}e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}dt \\
           & +\frac{1}{2}(-i+1)g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)(-i+1)^{2}e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}dt \\
            = &  g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)(-i-1)^{2}e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}dt \\
            & -\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)(-i+1)^{2}e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}dt
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
    f''+2if'-2f= \\
   = g(x) -\{(-i-1)^{2}+2i(-i-1)-2\}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(x-t)}dt \\
     -\{(-i+1)^{2}+2i(-i+1)-2\}\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-(t-x)}dt \\
   = g(x).
$$
I think there are errors in what was written in your problem. You can definitely see that what I have given you is correct because the final answer checks. So the final answer has been correctly verified to be
$$
                  f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i(x-t)}e^{-|x-t|}g(t)dt.
$$